# Trying to Bind Data to GridView But unable to Bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to bind data to gridView. Basically I want to bind particular persons record to gridview so to do this I fetch data via query. I had also set `AutoGenerateColumns=True`. My code executes fine but there is no exception and no error. Please check and guide. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class ViewRegisteredDonors : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conec = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloodDonorRegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        string query;
        query = "select D_FirstName,D_LastName,D_BloodGroup,D_City,D_Phone from Donor where D_City= @BG AND D_City=@cc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conec);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BG", dropbownBlood.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cc", DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.Text);
        conec.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet d = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(d);
        GridView1.DataSource = d;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you used the debugger, and if so what is the value of `d` after you step past this line `da.Fill(d);` do you see data either clicking the magnifying glass in the debugger or QuickWatch...? also you need to change this line `GridView1.DataSource = d` to 
`GridView1.DataSource = d.Tables[0]` you are filling a DataSet not a DataTable, DataTable is a subset of DataSet..

Comment: @MethodMan I rolled back your edit on this question, because you changed the code to something that would not compile. Please be careful when editing code in the question so that you don't change the meaning of the code.

Comment: @mason I did not think I changed anything then again it could have been a case of the fat fingering sorry

Comment: @MethodMan You edit was specifically to change it. You can't break a string up into multiple lines solely to enhance readability. Strings in C# can't span multiple lines unless you use a string literal, hence your edit changed the meaning of the code.

Comment: purely semantics anyway.. thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

Check your parameter name @cc.@ is missing so your dataset might be empty.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cc", DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.Text);
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cc", DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.Text);
```